# How to set QWidget cursor outside the GUI thread

Tags: qt

I am working on QT GUI project. In this application I have a QWidget as main window. I make the cursor from data coming from some source. When I set the cursor of widget. It gives me the following error.
QPixmap: It is not safe to use pixmaps outside the GUI thread
My code is as follows

```
void ImageWindow::setMouseCursor(unsigned char* data,unsigned char* maskbits,unsigned int length,int xHotSpot, int yHotSpot)
```

{

```
QBitmap bitmapData;
QBitmap bitmapMaskData;
bitmapData.loadFromData(data,length);
bitmapMaskData.loadFromData(maskbits,length);

this->setCursor(QCursor(bitmapData,bitmapMaskData,xHotSpot,yHotSpot));
this->update();
```

}

Function setMouseCursor is called from other class, which set the data of cursor.
ImageWindow is my customized QWidget class.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, the object which calls setMouseCursor lives outside the GUI thread as far as i can tell. In order to avoid this, make setMouseCursor a slot. Do not call the slot directly, instead emit a signal from the caller object, and connect that signal to setMouseCursor slot using Qt::QueuedConnection.

See : [ConnectionType](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum)

Answer (score 1):

Two problems:

- don't use a QBitmap outside the GUI-thread
- don't call gui objects `setCursor` outside the GUI-thread

> [Creating a Paint Device](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/paintsystem.html)
>   One advantage of using QImage as a
>   paint device is that it is possible to
>   guarantee the pixel exactness of any
>   drawing operation in a
>   platform-independent way. Another
>   benefit is that the painting can be
>   performed in another thread than the
>   current GUI thread.